# Block merge on BitBucket until Jenkins task is completed

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request

I'm looking for some way to block a possibility of making merge of pull requests on the BitBucket if some specified Jenkins task is currently running. Do you know if it is possible? I was looking for that in the Jenkins Git plugin and in the settings of BitBucket but with no success...
Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4):

In bitbucket go to the project and then the repository you want to enable this feature for, and under settings->pull request check the option

> Requires a minimum of [n] successful builds

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the bitbucket build status api.

1) Enable require minimum 1 successful builds in bitbucket repo settings
https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/11/18/introducing-the-build-status-api-for-bitbucket-cloud/

Then either:
Manually in jenkins pipeline fire the API calls to set the build status to in in progress, failed, success

Alternatively, using something like the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin which will do this automatically for you (sending the statuses) plus a host of other things (like automatically discovering new repos with Jenkinsfiles)

Comment: I am not sure if this is a thing I am looking for. As I understand, in that solution I need to specify a commit for which I should set the status. Am I right? But the thing is that I want to disable the possibility of merging of ANY of the commits if the specified jenkins job is running.

Comment: You do need to specify the commit, which will in most cases be the latest HEAD commit. The setting in bitbucket will block merges if the latest commit does not have a successful build status. So you won't be able to merge if the latest commit has not been built at all, if its in progress or if it failed. This sounds like it would work for your usecase as you described though.

Comment: This is to block merges to a branch unless the feature branch's build passes in Jenkins. I think what @wojtek1902 is asking for is to block merges to a branch while that same branch is building in Jenkins.